# Docker build fails with dependency issues even though I am satisfying them

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm looking for ideas as to why this is failing.
I've done the same steps on my host and they work well, the packages I'm calling out provide the needed dependencies.

**Build Command:**
`docker build -t testbuild .`

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/rhel7:latest

RUN  yum install  -y yum-utils
RUN  yum-config-manager --enable \
         EPEL_7_EPEL_7 \
         Community_mysql-connectors-community \
         Community_mysql-tools-community \
         Community_mysql57-community \
         rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64 \
         rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64 \
         rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64 \
         rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64 \
         rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms/7Server/x86_64

RUN true \
 && yum install  -y \
      cairo \
      yum-utils\
      collectd \
      openldap-devel \
      rrdtool \
      gcc \
      rrdtool-devel \
      pyrrd \
      rrdtool-python \
      python-ldap \
      wget \
      pycairo-devel \
      pycairo \
      python-devel \
      collectd-nginx \
      findutils \
      rrdtool \
      logrotate \
      memcached \
      nginx \
      nodejs \
      npm \
      redis \
      pkgconfig \
      sqlite \
      expect \
      git \
      python3\
      python3-devel\
      libffi-devel \
      postgresql-devel \
      postgresql-devel \
      mysql-community-client \
      mysql-community-libs \
      mysql-community-common \
      mysql-community-libs-compat
RUN yum clean all

RUN pip3 install \
      virtualenv\
# && /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv \
 && /usr/local/bin/virtualenv /opt/graphite \
 && . /opt/graphite/bin/activate \
 && pip3 install \
      PyMySQL \
      django==1.11.24 \
      django-statsd-mozilla \
      fadvise \
      gunicorn \
      msgpack-python \
      redis \
      rrdtool \
      python-ldap \
      mysqlclient \
      psycopg2
```

> **The error I am getting is**                     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: /opt/graphite/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-67zlal6a/rrdtool/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-67zlal6a/rrdtool/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
>            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-67zlal6a/rrdtool/
>       Complete output (5 lines):
>       /tmp/tmp_python_rrdtoolfr1k715h/test_rrdtool.c:2:17: fatal error: rrd.h: No such file or directory
>        #include 
>                        ^
>       compilation terminated.
>       Error: Unable to compile the binary module. Do you have the rrdtool header and libraries installed?
>       ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
>   full command output.

But I've ensured the files exist with the yum-installed packages.

I've  commented out this package and then I get a mysql_config error which I also don't get on my current test host.  Which leads me to believe  something is going wrong earlier in the build.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to RHEL repository, so I tried with centos 7 and was having same issues.

But **installing these additional packages helped** to successfully build image:

```
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y python36-pip
RUN yum install -y mysql mysql-devel
RUN yum install -y python36-devel
```

Here is final DockerFile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN  yum install  -y yum-utils
RUN  yum-config-manager --enable \
         EPEL_7_EPEL_7 \
         Community_mysql-connectors-community \
         Community_mysql-tools-community \
         Community_mysql57-community \
         rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64 \
         rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64 \
         rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms/7Server/x86_64 \
         rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64 \
         rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms/7Server/x86_64

RUN true \
 && yum install  -y \
      cairo \
      yum-utils\
      collectd \
      openldap-devel \
      rrdtool \
      gcc \
      rrdtool-devel \
      pyrrd \
      rrdtool-python \
      python-ldap \
      wget \
      pycairo-devel \
      pycairo \
      python-devel \
      collectd-nginx \
      findutils \
      rrdtool \
      logrotate \
      memcached \
      nginx \
      nodejs \
      npm \
      redis \
      pkgconfig \
      sqlite \
      expect \
      git \
      python3\
      python3-devel\
      libffi-devel \
      postgresql-devel \
      postgresql-devel \
      mysql-community-client \
      mysql-community-libs \
      mysql-community-common \
      mysql-community-libs-compat

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y python36-pip
RUN yum install -y mysql mysql-devel
RUN yum install -y python36-devel
RUN yum clean all

RUN pip3 install \
      virtualenv\
 && /usr/local/bin/virtualenv /opt/graphite \
 && . /opt/graphite/bin/activate \
 && pip3 install \
      PyMySQL \
      django==1.11.24 \
      django-statsd-mozilla \
      fadvise \
      gunicorn \
      msgpack-python \
      redis \
      rrdtool \
      python-ldap \
      mysqlclient \
      psycopg2
```